# How can I use jQuery to match nth-child or last if nth not found?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I need to be able to insert some markup into a document after() the second P element in a container. If there is only one element then I need to insert after() that one. nth-child simply does not make a match if there is only one element. How can I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select them both, and grab the first match.

```
$("#foo > p:nth-child(2), #foo > p:lastChild").eq(0).append(...;
```

Because the results are returned in document order, you can use the `0` index to get the `nth-child` or if it wasn't there, it'll get the last child.

---

If there are other element types, and you only care about the `p` elements, then use `nth-of-type` instead.

```
$("#foo > p:nth-of-type(2), #foo > p:lastChild").eq(0).append(...;
```